# App Inventor's apps resize background image and other content depending on screen size

Tags: background-image, autoresize, screen-size, app-inventor

I am programming with app inventor and I want my app to support all screen resolutions and aspect ratios and the background image and the other content resize depending on screen size. How can i do this?

More specific, I have a canvas fill parents, and I want the background image of this canvas fill also parent, but I can only set the size of this image by pixels. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said, you set the canvas width and height to fill parents. To make sure that this works also for the height, set screen.scrollable to false and test it on your device.

screenshot designer window
[image]

screenshot device

[image: screenshot]